# Backbone Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Learning Backbone JS these days. Iam getting below error: I am really not understanding what went wrong, so please look into below error and suggest me required changes in my code.

```
Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function wines.html:56
app.WineView.Backbone.View.extend.render wines.html:56
app.WinesListView.Backbone.View.extend.addOne wines.html:73
(anonymous function) underscore.js:70
h.each.h.forEach underscore.js:103
g.(anonymous function) backbone.js:966
app.WinesListView.Backbone.View.extend.addAll wines.html:69
f backbone.js:208
e.Events.trigger backbone.js:148
i.extend.reset backbone.js:770
t.success backbone.js:865
j jquery.js:3073
k.fireWith jquery.js:3185
x jquery.js:8251
(anonymous function)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
<div id="header">
    <input type="button" value="New Wine" />
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="wines-list"></ul>
</div>
<div id="content">

</div>

<script type="text/template" id="wine">
    <a href="#wines/<%= id %>">
        <%=n ame %>
    </a>
</script>


<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var app = {}

app.Wine = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "api/wines",
    defaults: {
        "id": null,
        "name": "",
        "grapes": "",
        "country": "USA",
        "region": "California",
        "year": "",
        "description": "",
        "picture": ""
    }
});

app.WinesList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Wine,
    url: 'api/wines'
});
app.winesList = new app.WinesList();
app.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: $('#wine').html(),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

app.WinesListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#sidebar',
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(app.winesList, 'reset', this.addAll);

        app.winesList.fetch({
            reset: true
        });
    },
    addAll: function() {
        app.winesList.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(wine) {
        wineView = new app.WineView({
            model: wine
        });
        $('.wines-list').append(wineView.render().el);
    }
});
app.winesListView = new app.WinesListView();
</script>
```

I already searched in google for this error, but didn't understood in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `wineView` the template attribute references the contents of an element (so in this case a string) which you are then trying to use as a function (hence the error)

try passing the element to the underscore template function then use this in your render to then pass your model

```
app.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template:  _.template($('#wine').html()),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to put _.template

Comment: this answer doesn't make much sense now that you have removed the part of the code from your question that I reference. For people reading this after the fact this will no longer be helpful if they can not identify the original error.